# Error in console when destroying autodesk viewer

Tags: debugging, autodesk-forge

I am using version 7.40.0 and there is an issue when I have disabled the spinner, it is trying to remove it from the dom but it is never created.

when `disabledSpinner = true`
[image]

then `creteDom` is never called

[image]

so it cannot access `this.domElement`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to be fixed in the Autodesk code.

edit: is solved in 7.44 https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/

Answer (score 0):

In "Terms of Service", about spinner:

(a) No Removal or Modification of Autodesk Brand Features. Except as otherwise offered by Autodesk, if the Autodesk Brand Feature (e.g., “Powered by Autodesk Forge®”) appears on any aspect of an Autodesk Forge Service (e.g., in the load screen and/or screen footer), You may not remove or modify it without Autodesk’s permission and You agree not to obscure or distort it.

Ref: https://www.autodesk.com/company/legal-notices-trademarks/terms-of-service-autodesk360-web-services/forge-platform-web-services-api-terms-of-service

Edit: Thanks for reporting, will update to viewer team.

Comment: This is offered by the config that can be passed to the viewer which is provided in API `disableSpinner`, is it really that case?

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood for distorting, will be reported to the viewer team to make the relevant fix.